# Inheriting a class that inherits np.ndarray

Tags: numpy, inheritance, numpy-ndarray

I read the docs on how to inherit `np.ndarray` (didn't understand it all the way through) as a subclass and found some information on how to inherit it. I think `class vector` inherits it correctly, but if I want to inherit `vector` in `ray` and extend the definition of `ray` how do I do that correctly? If possible I would appreciate it if anyone could elaborate again in maybe simpler terms why `np.ndarray` needs to be inherited the way it is.

```py
class vector(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return


class ray(vector):
    def __init__(self, origin, direction):
        self.origin = origin
        self.direction = direction
```

Comment: A big challenge when subclassing `ndarray` is making sure that all the (expected) array operations return the same subclass.  Without care `vector(np.arange)+3` could end up producing a `ndarray` rather than `vector`.

Comment: Correct, I think the `__new__` method takes care of this, but if I am to inherit this object in another class, and want to extend this - how would I do it correctly?